# Difference between creating a new list an mutating an existing one

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path

I'm trying to calculate the shortest path from a node `start` to another `end` in a graph. I've been reading that the `+` operator, applied to a list, concatenates an element to the end of the former, creating a new list as a result. Whereas using `.extend()` not only does the same of adding the elements to the end of the list but also keeps the same list instance.

I can't see why if I use `path = path + [start]` my code works, and not if I use `path.extend(start)`. I don't see the need of creating a new list each time the function is called for it to return the right results.

```
def shortest_path_edge_num(graph, start, end, path = None, shortest = None):
    if (graph or start or end) is None: return None
    if path is None: path = []
    if shortest is None: 
        shortest = []

    path = path + [start]
    # path.extend([start])
    # Base case:
    if start == end: return path

    for adj_node in graph[start]:
        if adj_node[0] not in path:
        new_path = shortest_path_edge_num(graph, adj_node[0], end, path, shortest)
            if new_path:
                if (not shortest) or (len(new_path) < len(shortest)):
                    shortest = new_path
    return shortest

# Main routine
graph = {
    'A' : [('B',5),('F',10)],
    'B' : [('A',5),('E',2),('C',4)],
    'C' : [('B',4),('D',11)],
    'D' : [('C',11),('E',7)],
    'E' : [('B',2),('D',7),('F',1)],
    'F' : [('A',10),('E',1)]
}

print shortest_path_edge_num(graph,'A','C')

>>> python graph.py
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> # But when changing to path.extend([start])
>>> python graph.py
['A', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'F']
```

**EDIT**

Using `+` creates a new instance of `list`, thus all the other variables that depend in some way of it don't change each time I add a new element to `path`. Now the question should be *how should I remove that dependence?*

Comment: Do you mean, you used path.extend([start])? Because extend() works only with 2 lists. Or are you using path.append(start) ?

Comment: I misspelled the `.extend()`. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

`path.extend()` is expecting another sequence as its argument.  The same as you said `path + [start]`, you need to say `path.extend([start])`.  The easier way, however, would be to use `.append()`: `path.append(start)`.  [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) are the docs on `list`.

Comment: My first approach was using `path.append(start)`, but as it didn't work, in fact `path.extend([start])` doesn't either, I tried with `+`.

Comment: Yes, it's the only way I can make it work, but I can't get why it does.

Comment: `path.append(start)` and `path.extend([start])` are equivalent to `path = path + [start]` (except that it effects other variables that refer to the same list).

Comment: The difference is that if I use `.append()` and assign to `new_path` the result of a function that uses `path` each `path.append(...)` will modify all other lists that depend in some way of that instance of `path`. That's why it only works with `+`.

Comment: Okay.  By the way, if you get tempted to use `path += [start]` to make it shorter, don't.  That is a shortcut for `path.__iadd__([start])`, so it will still modify all the others.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware that applying operations to `path` will result in modifications in other variables such as `new_path`or `shortest`. When I saw that doing `path.append(start)` or `path.extend([start])` also added `start` to the other two lists I realized that I should not use `path` when calling the function recursively in `new_path = shortest_path_edge_num(graph, adj_node[0], end, path, shortest)` but instead use `path[:]` so as to send a copy of the list and not the reference.

So in the end I kept the line `path.append(start)` or `path.extend([start])` and modified the parameter `path[:]` in the recursive call. By doing that the program returned the shortest path as expected.

Thanks for the comments and the answers.